# Similar matrices and their column space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, similar-matrices

Let $A$ be similar to $B$ (so $A=PBP^{-1}$). If we have a vector $v$ that's in the column space of $A$, then how do we show that $P^{-1}v$ is in the column space of $B$? I'm trying to figure out how the column spaces between $A$ and $B$ relate to each other but I seem to be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

$v$ being in the column space of $A$ means that there is some $u$ such that $Au = v$.

This means we have $PBP^{-1}u = v$.

The way to proceed is multiply both sides of the equation by $P^{-1}$. Can you see how to get to the answer from there?

Comment: I ended up getting P-1v=BP-1x. Would that be sufficient enough to say that P-1v is in the column space of B then? (Since Cx=P-1v where C=BP-1.)

Comment: Almost... The first step is correct. But the reason that $P^{-1}v$ is in the column space of $B$ is is not that it can be written as $Cx$, since that 'only' shows it is in the column space of $C$. We need a (very similar) argument that talks about $B$ instead